# Drupal 6 - Howto add custom antispam in Registration Form

Tags: validation, drupal, user-registration, spam-prevention

How can I add my own 'antispam' question in the default (/user/register) registration form?

This is what I want to do:

- Username  (default field)
- Email   (default field)
- Confirm Email (default field)
- Custom Antispam question  (What color is snow?)

So the user in this form has to answer the last question with 'white', otherwise he/she cannot register.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Custom Module approach:-
use hook_form_user_register_alter() to alter the default registration form to add your custom question field to the register form.

add a validation in $form['#validate'][]='your custom question validation function' in the form alter to validate if the question has been answered properly.

Existing Module:-
There appears to be a security question module(https://drupal.org/project/security_questions). You can look at this.

Comment: I guess I found the solution to my question...
It's called "Captcha Riddler". I will try this asap.